# Migrate SQL query from DB2 to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on migrating SQL code from DB2 to SQL Server 2012, I am new to SQL Server and stuck on this DB2 query:

```
select * from schema.tablename1 t1
 where (t1.column1,t1.column2)
 in
(select t2.column1,t2.column2 from
 schema.tablename2 t2)
```

How can we do the same in SQL Server?

Comment: Is there an error you are experiencing while trying to migrate the query? Please provide that information as well.

Comment: @NickRoth - SQL Server doesn't support tuples / row constructors with `IN`. You can only do `WHERE col1 IN (SELECT some_col ...)` not multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite this semi join using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   schema.tablename1 t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   schema.tablename2 t2
               WHERE  t1.column1 = t2.column1
                      AND t1.column2 = t2.column2)
```